# What was Bo-Katan's role in Death Watch?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

In season 5, it is clear that Pre Vizsla is the leader of the Death Watch.  However, the show focuses a great deal on Bo-Katan in this arc.  Was she the second-in-command of Death Watch?  Did she have some official role, or was she just Pre Vizsla's most trusted soldier?